# Malformed start tag. Attributes should be separated by whitespace.

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I have the following HTML as part of my SharePoint website (and this HTML was automatically generated from SharePoint itself), and it is not a custom web part :-

```
<td style="width:24px"><a id="WPQ2_nav_prev_a" href="javascript:MoveToDate('8\u002f13u002f2013','WPQ2');" ><img id="WPQ2_nav_prev_img"
src="/_layouts/15/1033/images/calprev.png"
width="19" height="19") /></a></td>
```

but when i validate my web site using IE F12 developer tools the console showed the following error on at the above code(specifically after the height="19"):-

> HTML1423: Malformed start tag. Attributes should be separated by
>   whitespace.

What is causing this / and how i can solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your markup should be like below

```
<td style="width:24px">
  <a id="WPQ2_nav_prev_a" href="javascript:MoveToDate('8\u002f13u002f2013','WPQ2');" >
    <img id="WPQ2_nav_prev_img" src="/_layouts/15/1033/images/calprev.png" width="19" height="19" />
  </a>
</td>
```

You have a closing bracket **)** after `height ="19"` in you code which may cause the error

Comment: not sure how to chnage it , as this is a purely SharePoint generated code ?

Comment: check in you sharepoint code there must be a **string** that generates this html and hence the closing bracket comes in picture.